# Workload Scheduler: error while opening the TCR administrator panel after a successful installation of the Dynamic Workload Console

Tags: dynamic, console, workload-scheduler

I have successfully installed the Dynamic Workload Console and its prereqs, but, when I try to open the TCR admin panel I get this error message:

Error!
Refresh Edit Minimize Maximize
PF-VAL-6171 Error retrieving metadata for the target fragment.
Details | Retry | Hide this message.
Details
DashboardException
PF-VAL-6171 Error retrieving metadata for the target fragment.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, try to rename or remove the following jar file:

```
BirtAdapterB.jar
```

path:

```
/reporting/lib/birt-runtime-2_2_2/ReportEngine/lib
```